# Error to Build Gradle when I Updating sdk versions

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I had faced following error when I update versions in Gradle:

```
C:\Users\03142\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\7e646e2ca904450b985ca981ac3ba677\res\values\values.xml

Error:(251, 5) error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/mode' with config ''.

Error:(251, 5) error: resource previously defined here.
```

How to Resolved it?

Comment: Try Rebuild Project With Invalidate Caches/Restart Also delete gradle folder

Comment: I already delete a appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar directory.. nothing happend.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined same resources for multiple times. Like you are using any module for your app but you initialled them multiple times in gradle file.

Comment: I am downgrade the Sdk from 27 to 26.  The problem to be solved. otherwise not cleared